# How to create a proper dockerfile for deploying on production node.js application using prisma and pm2 and running seeds only for first time?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, prisma, production

How can I run the seeds and migrate the latest schema updates and running using pm2.
Seed file is located in prisma/seed.js
Is that a proper dockerfile?

This is the current dockerfile I have.

```
# Use an official Node.js runtime as the base image
FROM node:16.15.1-alpine as builder

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the container
COPY package*.json ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install pm2 globally
RUN npm install pm2 -g

# Copy the rest of the application code to the container
COPY . .

# Generate the Prisma client
RUN npx prisma generate

# Generate the Prisma client
RUN npx prisma migrate deploy

# Expose the port on which your Node.js application will listen
EXPOSE 4500

# Set the command to run your Node.js application
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start", "index.js", "--name", "test-backend"]
```